# Xcode Beta 11: Where is the Host View Controller?

Tags: xcode, beta

I'm running XCode 11 Beta on Mohave and I can't see the Host View Controller, can anyone please confirm if they can see the "Host View Controller" in the Control Library if the are running on Catalina? The Host View Controller was demonstrated at WWDC and its not showing in my Library Controls.

I'm assuming that it might be a feature that is disabed when running on Mohave similar to the preview window that also does not show when running XCode 11 on Mohave. If someone could kindly verify that it is available if running on Catalina it would be greatly appreciated!

To verify this on Catalina with XCode 11 beta, open a storyboard, press Command-Shift-L to get a list of Library controls and look for a control named "Host View Controller"

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Yes, you must run Xcode on Catalina to use the Host View Controller. It will not show in the list of Objects on any previous macOSs.